# pandas reading excel results in "not a zip file"

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I try to read a xlsx into a data frame:

```
itut_ir = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\reportdata.xlsx')

print(itut_ir.to_string())
```

I receive this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\Reports\GOW\Report.py",
> line 44, in 
> df = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\reportdata.xlsx')
> File
> "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_base.py",
> line 304, in read_excel
> io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_base.py",
> line 824, in **init**
> self._reader = self.*enginesengine   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_xlrd.py",
> line 21, in **init**
> super().**init**(filepath_or_buffer)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_base.py",
> line 353, in **init**
> self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_xlrd.py",
> line 36, in load_workbook
> return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd_*init**.py",
> line 117, in open_workbook
> zf = zipfile.ZipFile(filename)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py",
> line 1222, in **init**
> self._RealGetContents()   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py",
> line 1289, in _RealGetContents
> raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file") zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

does anybody have an idea? the file does not seem to be broken, I can open it with Excel.

thanks!

*** UPDATE ***
the file producing the error is being downloaded from FTP. opening the original file works ... if that gives you a hint :) thanks

Comment: no need to use `open`, just the path to the file. Try: `pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\reportdata.xlsx', sheet_name='Details', skiprows=4)`

Comment: sorry, but I was misled by another error. breaking down the import I still get the zip error: itut_ir = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\reportdata.xlsx')

Comment: Is reportdata.xlsx the original file? Regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873423/xlsx-and-xlsm-files-return-badzipfile-file-is-not-a-zip-file) opening and saving the file may help.

Comment: hi, the file is being downloaded from an FTP server. I can open it via excel. not sure what you mean with open and save  thanks

Comment: ps: the file is not password protected

Comment: ahh it looks like that the file gets broken while downloading from FTP- copying the file manually works!

Comment: `xlsx` is basically a zip file, so it's likely that the file is broken when downloaded.

Comment: yeah, that was the case! thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue just a little bit ago with an XLSX that I created in LibreOffice.

The solution was to check the XLSX to make sure it wasn't corrupted. In my case, loading a previous version of the XLSX file corrected the problem.

Comment: Coming back to this issue because of this github thread [BUG: read_excel fuction return "zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file" #56810](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/56810), reporting that sensitivity tags may prevent reading the document. Makes me ask: What file corruption did you observe?