# pd.read_excel / ExcelWriter raise BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Tags: python, pandas, excel, concatenation, xlsxwriter

I am trying to concatenate a series of excel files with Pandas. I created a for loop to read in all file for a provided directory and I specified the sheet name alongside the columns I wanted to read in. Once I read those files I concatenated them as a DataFrame variable which I named 'list_of_df'.
I have tested my code up to the point where they are concatenated and I can see the error is initialized once I begin to concatenate the various excel sheets. Currently I am getting the error 'File is not a zip file'

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

df = []
list_of_df = pd.DataFrame()

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, 
                       sheet_name = 'cycle', 
                       usecols=['Chg. Cap.(mAh)','DChg. Cap.(mAh)'], 
                       engine = 'openpyxl')
    list_of_df = pd.concat([list_of_df. df], ignore_index = True)

print(list_of_df)

with pd.ExcelWriter('output3.xlsx',  engine = 'openpyxl', mode = 'a',) as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'output3')
```

This is the error raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\documents\python scripts\chg._and_dchg._curves_for_excel5.py:30
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = 'cycle', usecols=['Chg. Cap.(mAh)','DChg. Cap.(mAh)'], engine = 'openpyxl')

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:211 in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:331 in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py:482 in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py:1695 in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py:557 in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py:545 in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py:568 in load_workbook
    return load_workbook(

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py:315 in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py:124 in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py:96 in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\zipfile.py:1302 in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\zipfile.py:1369 in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Comment: Either the output3.xlsx you are trying to append or the files you are trying to read are not created properly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873423/xlsx-and-xlsm-files-return-badzipfile-file-is-not-a-zip-file. Does the error happen when trying to read or write the files?

Other than that, your append logic is also faulty. You need to do `list_of_df = pd.concat([list_of_df, df], ignore_index=True)`. Otherwise you are just rewriting list_of_df with the latest df.

Comment: Also @TeemuRisikko I added the list_of_df = pd.concat([list_of_df, df], ignore_index=True) but I am still getting the same type of error from my code.

Comment: @OCa trace back has been appended to the original code

Comment: Noticed something while brushing up your code formatting: in `pd.concat([list_of_df. df]`, that looks like a dot in there instead of the expected comma. Is this the exact code that gives the reported error? It needs to be. Feels this code snippet should be further trimmed down the a real MRE

Comment: Thank you for your comments @OCa. I believe you are correct, I just tried to print the 'df' variable and I obtained the same error. A bit confusing because I wasn't receiving it initially, I will check about the sensitivity labels. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the value from the comments:

1. The error traceback indicates that the issue is with the **reading** of the Excel files `df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = 'cycle', usecols=['Chg. Cap.(mAh)','DChg. Cap.(mAh)'], engine = 'openpyx)`, **not the writing** after concatenating, as you seemed to believe.
2. Possible causes have been reported:

- [pandas reading excel results in "not a zip file"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63596833/12846804) suggests either one or more input Excel files might be corrupted after ftp download (although no answer was accepted under that post). In which case, roll back to an earlier version of the guilty document(s)
- [xlsx and xlsm files return badzipfile: file is not a zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33873423/12846804) also suggests several hypotheses, may be related but the origin of your files matter.
- A recent github thread [BUG: read_excel returns "zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file" #56810](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/56810) suggests presence of sensitivity tag on the document, preventing reading. In which case, prior to anything, the tag has to be removed.

File corruption might be too easy a culprit and no evidence was given. The sensitivity tag on the other hand looks well documented.

Based on this, to turn this post into a useful one, both for you and present/future people experiencing the same issue,

- in the spirit of MRE, reformulate your post into reading one or two files that cause / don't cause the issue (a major edit that would be better done by yourself - might not be accepted if I do it)
- please come report your findings!