# How can I load an excel file in python with openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to work with excel sheets in python. I am not able to open the workbook by entering the path to the file or just the name entered as a variable. How can I solve this?

```
filename = 'file.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
```

I get the following error:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
  File "C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\zipfile.py", line 1269, in __init__     
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\zipfile.py", line 1336, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

However, if I put the file name directly in the function it loads it, and I do not get any error.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873423/xlsx-and-xlsm-files-return-badzipfile-file-is-not-a-zip-file

Comment: @miquelvir I've been reading and testing it and nothing works for me, I will keep trying things

Comment: If the file isn't a zipfile, it isn't an XLSX file.